# regex to only allow a single occurrence of a char next to each other

Tags: regex

So I have a current regx patten which matches how I want.

However I need to only allow for a single occurrence of say a `/` or `-` at any one time.

i.e.

```
allowed: /name/amp/test-123
not allowed: /name//amp/test-123
not allowed: /name/amp/test--123
```

[This is my current regex](https://regex101.com/r/UsGHve/2):

```
([\w\/]+)\/amp(\/[\w-\/]+)
```

It matches those below correctly:

```
/name/name/amp/world-12345678/
/name/name/amp/world-12345678
/name/amp/snooker/12345678
/name/amp/snooker/12345678/
/name/amp/snooker/12345678
```

These strings should not be matched, but my regex matches them:

```
/name/amp/snooker//12345678
    #this shouldnt match because of the double `/`
/name/name/amp/world--12345678
    #this shouldnt match because of the double `-`
```

Comment: I did, thats what is under the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my two cents :

[Example regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UsGHve/3)

```
([\w\/]+)\/amp(\/\w+[-\/]\w+\/?)
```

`(\/\w+[-\/]\w+\/?)` Means :

```
- \/    -> Match literally "/"
- \w+   -> Match 1 or more character like [a-zA-Z0-9_]
- [-\/] -> (Here is the magic) Match literally "-" or "/" only once
- \w+   -> Match 1 or more character like [a-zA-Z0-9_]
- \/?   -> Match literally "/" zero or one time
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How is it different from @WiktorStribiżew answer?

Comment: This works great too, thanks again. I am going to use this one, as it also excludes the trailing `/`

Comment: @chinds: Check [the above regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UsGHve/4), it does not match potentially valid inputs.

Comment: @toto, the solution of Wiktor take care of potentially valid inputs. This one is more simple. I'm agree to say the Wiktor's answer is better. But it fills the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decompose the character class into a group based subpattern and make sure you allow a trailing `/` with `\/?`, and add anchors:

```
^([\w\/]+)\/amp(\/\w+(?:[-\/]\w+)*)\/?$
^                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CggtEE/1)

The `^` anchors the match at the string start, `$` anchors it at the string end, and `\w+(?:[-\/]\w+)*` matches:

- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:[-\/]\w+)*` - a non-capturing group matching zero or more sequences of the following subpatterns:

  - `[-\/]` - either `-` or `/`
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

Comment: I do not think the other regex actually works in all the scenarios (especially if there are more than 1 hyphens). The `/` at the end is *optional* in my regex. See the `?` quantifier that makes an atom match 1 or 0 times.