# Match exactly one occurrence and not consecutive occurrences

Tags: r, regex

I have a file name with directory path returned from `list.files(..., full.names = T)`. I want to split the file name up by `/` to find the directory structure. I am having trouble only identifying single occurrences of `/`, e.g.

```
strsplit("C://dir1/dir2/txt.R", "/")
# [[1]]
# [1] "C:"    ""      "dir1"  "dir2"  "txt.R"
```

when I desire the output to be:

```
[1] "C://"  "dir1"  "dir2"  "txt.R"
```

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42134239) that seems to give a regex answer, however, I get an error when I try to get a 'literal' match:

```
> strsplit("C://dir1/dir2/txt.R", "\/")
Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\/"
```

In fact, the regex in that example does not work in `R`:

```
> grepl('([\w\/]+)\/amp(\/\w+[-\/]\w+\/?)', '/name/amp/test-123')
Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'([\w"
```

Comment: Split by using: [`(?<=\/\/)|(?<!\/)\/(?!\/)`](http://rubular.com/r/By9Mx02OYf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to match more than one occurence of `/` and `SKIP` it while splitting on the single `/` or the word boundary that succeeds after the `/`

```
strsplit("C://dir1/dir2/txt.R", "[/]{2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b[/]|(?<=[/])\\b", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "C://"  "dir1"  "dir2"  "txt.R"
```

Comment: wow. 1) I had no idea it was going to be so complicated. 2) How did you come up with this regex so quickly?

Comment: @Alex Thanks.  I was following the logic you described to skip those matches where it is more than one `/`

Comment: Great answer.  This way over my head, and I am #9 rank for the week +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Thanks, yes, glad to know that you are in top 10.  Keep it up

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
strsplit("C://dir1/dir2/txt.R", "(?<=//)|(?<!/)/(?!/)", perl=TRUE)
```

[**See output here**](http://rextester.com/UHXW36026)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=//)` - finds the position immediately preceded by a `//`
- `|` - OR
- `(?<!/)/(?!/)` - matches a `/` which is neither preceded by a `/` nor followed by a `/`

[**Regex Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/By9Mx02OYf)

Answer (score 2):

KISS,

```
strsplit("C://dir1/dir2/txt.R", "\\b/\\b|(?<=//)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "C://"  "dir1"  "dir2"  "txt.R"
```

Comment: Avinash, word boundaries may not work well here, especially if there are non-word chars before or after `/`. I understand it is not the current scenario, just FYI.

Comment: Yep, @WiktorStribiżew I agree. If it's a question related to R, answer for current context would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple matching approach would be

```
x <- "C://dir1/dir2/txt.R"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^/]+(?://)?", x))
#  or with stringr
str_extract_all(x, "[^/]+(?://)?")
# [[1]]
# [1] "C://"  "dir1"  "dir2"  "txt.R"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9oY0Yl/1) and the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/x9Ph6m).

**Pattern details**

- `[^/]+` - 1 or more chars other than `/`
- `(?://)?` - an optional sequence of two `/`.

**Note** that in case you want to ignore `//` inside the path and only grab them in the beginning, you may add an alternative like `^[[:alpha:]]://` or a lookbehind `(?<=^[[:alpha:]]:)` to the optional group:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^/]+(?:(?<=^[[:alpha:]]:)//)?", x, perl=TRUE))
# or
regmatches(x, gregexpr("^[[:alpha:]]://|[^/]+", x))
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/9oY0Yl/3) and [that regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9oY0Yl/4).